# jQuery cannot get id from $(this) button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use `jQuery` (`this`) to get the id of a button clicked and pass that id to a function to do something with. I have three buttons all with  different id's and was hoping to use `$(this)` as I am learning it but cannot get it to work no matter what way I try it
This is the code

```html
<html>
<title>QuizMaster</title>
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <script src="jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
 function player(x){
  var player = x;
  console.log(player);
 }

 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#button').click(function(){
   var x = $(this).id;
   player(x);
  });
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <form id='button'>
  <input type='button' id='reset' value='Reset'>
  <input type='button' id='player1' value='Player1'>
  <input type='button' id='player2' value='Player2'>
 </form>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: $(this).attr("id");

also, html ending tag is incorrect and title tag should be inside the head tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should listen to input element not #button. And you should get id with `.attr()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#button input').click(function(){
            var x = $(this).attr("id");
            player(x);
        });
    });
```

Comment: This worked all the suggestions for ('button input') worked so thankyou i was not looking at this part. Did not need attr as it works all ok with this.id

Comment: Happy to know it worked, but I still cannot understand how `$(this).id` could work!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<title>QuizMaster</title>
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script>
 function player(x){
  var player = x;
  console.log(player);
 }

 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type="button"]').click(function(){
   var x = $(this).attr('id');
   player(x);
  });
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <form id='button'>
  <input type='button' id='reset' value='Reset'>
  <input type='button' id='player1' value='Player1'>
  <input type='button' id='player2' value='Player2'>
 </form>
</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[type=button]').click(function(){
            var x = $(this).attr('id')
player(x);
});
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Like this:

```js
 function player(x){
  var player = x;
  console.log(player);
 }

 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#button :button').click(function(){
   var x = $(this).attr('id');
   player(x);
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form id="button">
  <input type="button" id="eset" value="Reset">
  <input type="button" id="player1" value="Player1">
  <input type="button" id="player2" value="Player2">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may get the **id** simply referring to the [event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) element. Moreover, you don't need to transform the **this** keyword to a jQuery object and then apply the **.attr** method: the short form is:  this.id.

The snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#button').on('click', function(e){
    var x = e.target.id;
    console.log('button pressed is: ' + x);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id='button'>
  <input type='button' id='reset' value='Reset'>
  <input type='button' id='player1' value='Player1'>
  <input type='button' id='player2' value='Player2'>
</form>
```